# Making a map using a 2d array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am at the beginning of making a platformer game in pygame and following some requirements I am meant to implement a 2d array. I'm not very familiar with them and I am having a problem using the data from my .csv file to accordingly add the corresponding tile image. I have all the files to that the number in the file would load the same tile with the name "Tile_[number].png"

I tried to check what what image should be loaded and then add the corresponding image to a 2d array but when trying to add the the file name I get a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 : "Tile_36.png"

I am unsure on how I am meant to add the file the the 2d array, if I should use the file name or if I should use the pygame.image.load() function or if I have to give the path of the file cause all my tiles are inside a folder.

## **Main.py**

```
import pygame

from level import Tilemap


map = Tilemap()
Array = map.initArray("project.csv")
Array = map.PopArray("project.csv")
print(Array)
```

## **level.py**

```
import pygame


class Tilemap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tile_size = 32
        self.start_x = 0
        self.start_y = 0

    def initArray(self, filename):
        cols = 0
        rows = 0
        file = open(filename,"r")

        for line in file:
            columns = line.split(",")
            cols = len(columns)

            rows += 1

        self.tiles = [[0] * cols for i in range(rows)]
        file.close()
        

    def PopArray(self, filename):
        file = open(filename, "r")
        rowcounter = 0
        colcounter = 0
        for line in file:
            colcounter = 0
            data = line.split(",")
            for x in range(len(data)):

                if int(data[colcounter]) == -1:
                    self.tiles[rowcounter][colcounter] = -1

                elif int(data[colcounter]) >=0 and int(data[colcounter])< 10:
                    self.tiles[rowcounter][colcounter] = int("Tile_" + data[colcounter] + ".png")

                else:
                    self.tiles[rowcounter][colcounter] = int("Tile_" + data[colcounter] + ".png") 
                colcounter += 1
            rowcounter += 1
          
        file.close()
        return self.tiles
```

Comment: You're trying to convert the string "Tile_36.png" to an integer, and there's no way to do that. The `int` function expects a number as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess I never known that you can have a 2d array of integers and a 2d array of string. I had declared a 2d array of integers which is where I was going wrong when trying to add my files as they couldn't be made in to integers since they contain both characters and integers.

I changed the code so that it was now

```
self.tiles = [[""] * cols for i in range(rows)]:
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your code here: `int("Tile_" + data[colcounter] + ".png")`

It is trying to cast a string to an integer, but it cannot cast "Tile_36.png" to an integer.